# How to read xml file from a word document with javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, ms-word, document, docx

I am trying to extract the xml file from my word document.
I have added my custom output.xml file and I want to read it with Javascript.

[See this image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jokH.png)

Comment: Hey @vatsal, just so I understand your question. Are you trying to run this program in a browser or from the command line?

Comment: I am running in browser, I need to display that custom output.xml file in html page.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/officedev/pnp-officeaddins/word-add-in-load-and-write-open-xml/  << try to refer this hope you get some idea

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/ee872374(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/ee872374(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#adding-the-sample-code-to-the-solution